# Solving Euler's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the following Euler's equation:

$$r^2 B_n'' + r B_n' - n^2 B_n = 3 \delta_{n1} r^2$$

Such that the solution is:

$$B_n(r) = \beta_n r^n + \delta_{n1}r^2, \forall n \ge 1$$

where $\beta_{n}$ is a free coefficient and $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta function.

Comment: Well if you know a probable solution you can substitute it in the given equation and show that it's indeed a solution.

Comment: $B$ is for differentiate with respect to what?